# Will $\gamma =\frac{|\vec a \vec b|^2}{|\vec a \vec c|^2}=\frac{||\vec b||^2}{||\vec c||^2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If $\vec a$ is a $1 \times 7 $ row vector,and $\vec b$ and $\vec c$  are both $7 \times 1 $ column vector,but $\vec b \neq\vec c$.

Now we know $||\vec b||^2=\vec b^H \vec b $,and $||\vec c||^2=\vec c^H \vec c $

If $\gamma=\frac{|\vec a \vec b|^2}{|\vec a \vec c|^2},$ will $\gamma =\frac{||\vec b||^2}{||\vec c||^2}$?if yes,how to prove it?

$\vec a \vec b$ is a scalar,not a vector.

Comment: you got $|\vec{a}\vec{b}|=\|a\|\|b\|\cos (\theta)$

Comment: so you mean $\gamma \neq \frac{||\vec b||^2}{||\vec c||^2}$.because the $cos(\theta_{ab})$ may not be equal to $cos(\theta_{ac})$?